# Facebook API, get page post link (PHP)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Here's some code:

```
$facebookUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$facebookPageId.'/posts?&access_token='.$facebookAppId.'|'.$facebookAppSecret;
$facebookData = json_decode(curlRequest($facebookUrl))->data;
```

`curlRequest` is successfully returning data but it's limited.  The response has the following items:

- message
- story
- created_time
- id

It's bad enough these don't include a photo (which all of these posts do) but what's worse is that I have no link that takes me to the post.

Twitter has a redirect using `'https://twitter.com/statuses/'. $post->id;` does Facebook have something similar?  Or better yet how do I get all of the data for these posts?

Comment: Answering half of my question: `$thePost['link'] = 'http://www.facebook.com/'.explode("_", $post->id)[0].'/posts/'.explode("_", $post->id)[1];` will get the link to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link to the post would be

```
$facebookUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$facebookPageId.'/posts?&access_token='.$facebookAppId.'|'.$facebookAppSecret;
$facebookData = json_decode(curlRequest($facebookUrl))->data;

$link = "http:/fb.com/".$facebookData->id; //This short link will redirect to the pages' post
```

The `$facebookData->id` is made up of unique values i.e. the part before "_" (underscore) describes the parent (page,user,group,event) and string after underscore is the post id of its parent.

Comment: That's definitely helpful, but what about the other attributes that should be on the post (`picture`, `link`, etc)? I'm having the same issue as @fauxserious, and the FB docs suggest there should be a lot more data coming back in each Post object - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/post#read

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Nishant's helpful answer above, Facebook has a lot of other data you can get as part of the Post object, as outlined in [their docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/post#read). By default, though, all it sends is

- message
- story
- created_time
- id

In order to retrieve any other fields, the request has to specify those fields in the query params. For example, if I want the `picture` and `link` associated with a Post, I would construct my GET request thus:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID?fields=picture,link&access_token=YOUR_TOKEN
```

And I would get a response like this:

```
{
  "link": "http://example.com/link",
  "picture": "https://example.com/picture",
  "id": POST_ID
}
```

I don't know PHP so can't give the specific syntax for OP's question, but this should get you most of the way there.

Answer (score 0):

Example link for Facebook post:

```
facebook.com/123123123/posts/890890890/
```

pattern:

```
facebook.com/{{page_id}}/posts/{{post_id}}/
```

where from API post_id => {{page_id}}_{{post_id}}